# Rails query for inner joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, inner-join

```
clients :has_many :project,:roles
```

I have implement but its not a good implementation..

Comment: Could you try and explain what you're trying to achieve a little better?

Comment: simonmorley I have updated my question,please let me if you have any query?

Comment: I still don't really understand you question. Have you watched one of these railscasts? http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`joins` can be used several levels deep, for example that Activity belongs to Carrier
    Activity.joins(:carrier => {:projects => {:client => :roles}})

will generate sql along the lines of

```
SELECT * from activities
JOIN carriers on activities.carrier_id = carriers.id
JOIN projects on carriers.id = projects.carrier_id
JOIN clients on projects.client_id = clients.id
JOIN roles on roles.client_id = clients.id
```

to which you can add your conditions. You'll need to qualify you column names, i.e. use `projects.id` instead of just `id` so that your database knows which `id` you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good enough. Maybe you can improve it like this:

```
clients = Client.joins(:roles).where("roles.name in ('responsible', 'replacement')")
client_ids = clients.map(:&id)
projects = Project.where('id in (?) && start=? && stop=?',client_ids,params[:start_time],params[:end_time])
project_ids = projects.map(:&id)
carriers = Carrier.joins(:projects).where('projects.id in (?) AND carriers.has_clients=1', project_ids)
carrier_ids = carriers.map(&:id)
activities = Activity.joins(:carriers).where('carriers.id in (?)', carrier_ids)
```